# What is the prescribed way to maintain multiple VueJS, @vue/cli dependent applications over time?

Tags: vue.js, npm, vuejs2, yarnpkg

Global NPM dependencies make me a bit nervous.  I've developed several applications that need to be stable, rebuildable for years.  Tools like @vue/cli are great, initially, but I'm concerned that as time goes by, the tool will be updated, but the products I've built will still need the earlier versions.  So, ideally, all of their dependencies would be specified and included within the project folders.  @vue/cli is designed to be installed globally and then generates package.json files specifying a set of additional @vue/cli dev dependencies.  I tried installing the @vue/cli locally, but that only works if it's installed within a parent, container directory, which doesn't work well with monorepo setups. (Lerna will hoist and link common dependencies and @vue/cli can no longer find it's dependencies in the application directories it creates, where it expects them.)

Is there a recommended way to install @vue/cli locally so that I can maintain a set of applications over a long period of time, which may each have been initialized with different versions of @vue/cli?